# document.getElementById() is getting Null

Tags: javascript, html

```
function createDiv(nameId,width,height,color)
{
    try
    {
        // Initialize And Create Div
        if(document.createElement('div'))
        {
            // document.write("<br>Create Div Success");
            if((nameId.length!=0) && (width>0) &&(height>0) && (color.length!=0))
            {
                //creating div
                var divCreate = document.createElement('div');

                divCreate.id=nameId;
                document.getElementById(nameId).width = width;
                document.getElementById(nameId).height = height;
                document.getElementById(nameId).background = color;
                document.getElementById(nameId).backgroundColor = "Red";
                document.body.appendChild(divCreate);
                document.write(" <br>Create Div Success And Added To Body");

                // document.write(" <br>Create Div Success And Added To Body");
            }
            else
            {
                //     document.write("<br>All Field Value Required");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            document.write("<br>Unable To Create Div");
        }
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        document.write("<br>"+e);
    }
}
```

`document.getElementById()` is getting `Null`. I am trying to create a DIV using javascript and assigning some width/height and color to it, but its not working. However, if I use the code below the div gets created but it's not visible on the screen. And if I use the function `createDiv()` it does not work.

```
divCreate.id=nameId;
divCreate.width = width;
divCreate.height = height;
divCreate.background = color;
divCreate.backgroundColor = "Red";
document.body.appendChild(divCreate);
```

Comment: Read up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 1):

createElement only creates the element..
you need to first add the element to the document for it to be found..

Try to add the append earlier and that should work:

```
      //creating div
      var divCreate = document.createElement('div');

      divCreate.id=nameId;
      document.body.appendChild(divCreate); <-----------------------
      document.getElementById(nameId).width = width;
      document.getElementById(nameId).height = height;
      document.getElementById(nameId).background = color;
      document.getElementById(nameId).backgroundColor = "Red";

      document.write(" <br>Create Div Success And Added To Body");
```

Comment: Technically correct, though it is still better to just refer to `divCreate` instead of re-fetching it from the DOM for every assignment with `gEBI`

Comment: very true Dennis. you have the object so just use it, rather than take  the scenic walk down the dom ;)

Answer (score 0):

Appears you are trying to reference it before you append it.

Comment: but i am not able to see the div in the browser<script>
    //Run Code Here
    var divExample = new createDiv("DivTest",100,100,"#000001");
</script>

Answer (score 0):

There a few items that need to be improved/fixed in your code:

- You already have the object, so you dont need to use the `getElementById` function to get it (Also, you tried to get object before adding it to the body)
- You need to use the `.style` to access the `css` properties of the object
- Dont use the `document.write` function to print a status, because it will rewrite the page if the page already was loaded.

Here is the updated code:

```
//creating div
      var divCreate = document.createElement('div');

      divCreate.id=nameId;
      //to access the width and other css properties, you need to use the style
      divCreate.style.width = width;
      divCreate.style.height = height;
      divCreate.style.background = color;
      divCreate.style.backgroundColor = "Red";
      document.body.appendChild(divCreate);
```

Comment: hi,but i ma not able to get the div in a browser

Comment: so in the browser, you use the document.getElementById function... in this case you dont need because you already have the reference of the object when you use the document.createElement

Comment: nothing gets displayed in the browser.

Comment: please edit your question and post the full code html/js